# Problem with a Graphic

Tags: graphics

[image]
Could someone tell me why the graph looks like this? And you could help me solve it?
I am using a template, which my teacher made for the class to use

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should post a minimal, yet complete,  example code reproducing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it is better to post the code inside of the question. Also, make a new example document that can be compiled and shows only the graphic, and nothing else. In that way all the necessary information is contained in the question here, which helps to prevent links that no longer work, or people needing to visit external sites. Also, isolating the issue allows people to start looking for a solution immediately without spending time to understand which parts of the document are relevant for the question and which parts are not.

Comment: Don't put links to overleaf in public forum, even read-only links will show your email address to everybody https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8403/138900